Using WebviewUrl::App with a Tauri HTTP Server
I have a "server" that is a desktop application. With this, I can use Warp to start an HTTP port on the local network, which can be accessed from other browsers on the network. These browsers would be the clients.
Recently, I successfully experimented with displaying the index.client.html file, created alongside index.html, as a response to the started port.
Now, I thought about connecting the Vite-generated frontend as well (instead of creating two separate frontend apps for the server and the client, since I would use almost the same components for both).
However, when opening index.client.html, it cannot find the associated JS and CSS files. When I use warp::path::full to redirect them, it's almost a success, but I ran into issues with MIME types: I tried a few tools. Based on the file names, it worked since there are special files, and almost all of them are text/javascript. I didn't get good results when trying based on content. Manually handling it seemed clunky.
Is there a way to stream this application, which is displayed in the Tauri desktop window, through a specific port?
Or is it not possible, and I should create a separate Vite project for the client? (In that case, I would be interested in some sources explaining why it's not possible, as I'm still learning the limits of Tauri v2.)
